# URLs in Win32 VERSIONINFO resources?

Tags: winapi, versioning, versioninfo

One of our managers has decided that the CompanyName in our EXE/DLL files (in the VERSIONINFO resource) should contain our URL (e.g. "OurCompany - http://www.ourcompany.com").

I think this is a bad idea, because it could lead to unintended consequences. It also offends the aesthete in me, because the field's not call CompanyNameAndUrl, and our company name isn't a URL.

Am I right? How can I persuade him he's wrong? Where should I put a URL to get it to appear in the Version information in Windows.

Am I wrong?

Update: the binaries are digitally-signed, so the URL's visible in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authoritative answer and example in this case should come from Microsoft:

[VERSIONINFO Resource (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx)

> **CompanyName**: Company that produced the file—for example, "Microsoft Corporation" or "Standard Microsystems Corporation, Inc." This string is required.

Very few people will ever look at a properties of an executable file or a DLL; and out of those who do, I would guess 95% know how to Google the *ProductName* to find out more about it. I have checked several files from various vendors on my PC and none of them includes a URL.

However, if you must, there is always the *Comments* field...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to MaxVT's comments - using non-clickable full URLs is **so** last century.

IMO: it doesn't hurt, probably noone will ever see it, and from time to time you have to gie your managers the feeling they are in control of something.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a URL associated with your module, why not attach a digital signature? That way you get the added benefit for you and the client of knowing the file is untampered with, and the default viewer will show the URL as a clickable link.